# Looking for MS Japanese Font

Tags: font

I am working with a client who is looking for a specific Japanese font for her Mac system.
This has been told to me because her co-worker has Catalina and the following fonts installed.

[image]

The specific font they are looking for is called MS 明朝（minchyo).

Where can I find this font on or for a mac?

Comment: Presumably you would have it present if you installed MS Office.

Comment: That was my thought also. She said she had an MS office on her mac. Maybe it's the version of office that matters?

Comment: Ask her to look in the font menu for Word.  For me it is very close to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Word stores its fonts at a special location.  If you see MS Mincho on the Word font menu, you can probably extract it from this location to put in Font Book for use in other apps if necessary.  The location is  /Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts